# Finding number of groups that can be formed.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, combinations

I was asked to find number of different binary operation which forms a groups for a set containing 4 elements in a class test.

---

So first what i did was select an identity element 'e'. (Let other element be a,b,c)

Necessary conditions :- ee=e , ae=ea=a , ec=ce=c ,  eb=be=b

---

case 1) aa=e , bb = e  , cc=e

Now ab cannot be equal to e (that would imply a=b) or a,b (that would imply b=e or a=e).

Similarly , ab=ba=c , ac=ca=b , bc=cb=a

(Only one way from 3 elements)

---

Case 2) ab=ba=e and that would imply cc=e

As pointed above : bc=cb=a , ca=ac=b

(ab)c=a(bc) implies c=aa and similarly bb= c

(3 ways to do from 3 elements , selecting x such that xx=e has 3 ways)

---

Then i checked associativity for both case 1 and case 2 , which pretty much holded .

So the ways of what we want is = (numer of ways to select an identity element) × (number of ways of (case1) + number of ways of (case2))

= 4×(1+3)=16.

---

Is the method and answer correct. And as you can see it's not really a good method (especially due to need of checking of associativity).

Is there more simple way of checking associativity (i made each combination and checked it). Is there a more simpler way to do this , or for a general 'n' or can we just do it for smaller 'n'  by only  counting each case? Is there any recursions that we can develop?

Any thoughts , link , a way to make calcutions etc. , All are appreciated. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your answer couldn't be more wrong. [this](https://oeis.org/wiki/Number_of_groups_of_order_n) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_isomorphism)  might help

Comment: Thanks but they consider only the type of group. Here we have to select identity elements but for 'type of group' that does not matter. Still it's showw some gr8 work.Further i just want a group , i don't need it to be isomorphism on G×G.

Comment: @Babydesta Your comment couldn't be more wrong. The answer is correct, as it did not mention isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

The slightly more advanced way to do this for a set of size $n$ is to compute the isomorphism types of groups of order $n$, then compute $n!\sum \frac{1}{|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|}$, where the sum runs over the isomorphism types. For $n=4$, there are two isomorphism types: $C_4$, with automorphism group of order $2$, and $C_2^2$, with automorphism group of order $6$. So we get $4!(1/2+1/6)=16$.

Comment: Could you a provide a link where it provide detailed discussion on this topic?